# R Syntax for converting date to SAS date9 format but the date should be numeric and only format should change

Tags: r

Consider that I have a date i.e. 2017-10-23, and want the result to look 23OCT2017

```r
date <- '2017-10-23'

date2 <- toupper(format(as.Date('2017-10-23'),'%d%b%Y'))
str(date2)
```

```
chr "23OCT2017"
```

however this results in character date, however i want that to be numeric but the format should be  23OCT2017. Could any suggest how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't really have the idea of a "format", which I suspect is something you've got from SAS.

What you can do is create a new class, and write a print method for that class to show the values in anyway you like. For example, if I create:

```
print.d9 = function(x){
    print(
      toupper(
        format(
         as.Date(unclass(x),origin="1970-01-01"),
         '%d%b%Y')))
}
```

Then a numeric vector looks like numbers:

```
> v = c(0, 366, 1000)
> v
[1]    0  366 1000
```

until I re-class it as "d9":

```
> class(v) = c("numeric","d9")
```

and then it prints using the `print.d9` function:

```
> v
[1] "01JAN1970" "02JAN1971" "27SEP1972"
```

But the underlying data are numeric:

```
> v
[1] "01JAN1970" "02JAN1971" "27SEP1972"
> v+30
[1] "31JAN1970" "01FEB1971" "27OCT1972"
```

But this is only half the job, for example as is you can't put these into a data frame and still see the character representation:

```
> data.frame(x1=v)
    x1
1    0
2  366
3 1000
```

Yeah there's ways round this, but any sensible code would use native R dates as much as possible and only convert to a specific date format at the last moment. R's date objects are numeric and can be put in data frames, unlike my `d9` class above. And you've already written code to convert to the format you want.